# Passing and Parsing an Array from one shell script to another

Tags: arrays, bash, parameters

Due to the limitation of 9 parameters in a script, my objective is to pass about 30 strings bundled in an array from calling script (scriptA) to called script (scriptB).

My scriptA looks something like this...

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr=( ab "c d" 123 "string with spaces" 456 )
. ./scriptB.sh "Task Name" "${arr[@]}"
```

My scriptB looks something like this...

```
#!/bin/bash
arg1="$1"
shift
arg2=("$@")
read -a arr1 <<< "$@"
j=0
for i in "${arr1[@]}"; do
#echo ${arr1[j]}
((j++))
case "$j" in
"1")
param1="${i//(}"
echo "$j=$param1"
;;
"2")
param2="${i}"
echo "$j=$param2"
;;
"3")
param3="${i}"
echo "$j=$param3"
;;
"4")
param4="${i}"
echo "$j=$param4"
;;
"5")
param5="${i//)}"
echo "$j=$param5"
;;
esac
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
1=ab
2=c
3=d
4=123
5=string
```

Problem:

```
1. I see parenthesis ( and ) gets added to the string which I have to strip them out
2. I see an array element (with spaces) though quoted under double quotes get to interpreted as separate elements by spaces.
```

Comment: Are others able to see my question? Its been 4 days and no one seems to attempt it yet.

Comment: `read -a arr1 <<< "$@"` No. `I see parenthesis ( and ) gets added to the string which I have to strip them out` Where do you see them? There is no question in your post. And I do not understand the problems. What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: `I see parenthesis ( and )` That would only be possible if you have qouted them. [I could not reproduce](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/DarkMurkyAdministrators#main.sh)

Answer (score 0):

> `read -a arr1 <<< "$@"`

is wrong. The `"$@"` here is equal to `"$*"`, and then `read` will split the input on whitespaces (spaces, tabs and newlines) and also interpret `\` slashes and assign the result to array `arr1`. Remember to use `read -r`.

Do:

```
arr1=("$@")
```

to assign to an array. Then you could print with:

```
for ((i=1;i<${#arr1};++i)); do 
   printf "%d=%s\n" "$i" "${arr1[$i]}"
done
```

> of 9 parameters in a script, my objective is to pass about 30 strings bundled in an array from calling script (scriptA)

Ok. But `"${arr[@]}"` is passing multiple arguments anyway. If you want to pass array as string, pass it as a string (note that [eval is evil](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)):

```
arr=( ab "c d" 123 "string with spaces" 456 )
./scriptB.sh "Task Name" "$(declare -p arr)"
# Then inside scriptB.sh, re-evaulate parameter 2:
eval "$2" # assigns to arr
```

Note that the `scriptB.sh` is sourced in your example, so passing arguments.... makes no sense anyway.

> I see an array element (with spaces) though quoted under double quotes get to interpreted as separate elements by spaces

Yes, because you interpreted the content with `read`, which splits the input on characters in `IFS`, which by default is set to space, tab and newline. You could print arguments on separate lines and change IFS accordingly:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -a arr1 < <(printf "%s\n" "$@")
```

or even use a zero terminated string:

```
mapfile -t -d '' arr1 < <(printf "%s\0" "$@")
```

but those are just fancy and useless ways of writing `arr1=("$@")`.

Note that in your code snipped, `arg2` is an array.